# Client code is unable to read data from server [sockets]

Tags: c, sockets

My objective is to implement a simple data transfer from server to client. The problem is that the client is unable to read data from the server most of the time (it only works sometimes) even though the server says that the transfer was successful.

### server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 8080

void main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), option = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char source_file[] = "<path>/something.txt"; 
    char fname[] = "something.txt";

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address)) == -1){
        perror("Could not bind to address");
        return;
    }
    if(listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
        perror("Error while listening to connections");
        return;
    }
    int new_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &address, &addrlen);
    
    if(new_socket == -1){
        perror("Error connecting to client");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else printf("Connected to client\n");

    // first send the filename
    if(send(new_socket, fname, sizeof(fname), 0) == -1){
        perror("Error while sending file");
        return;
    }
    printf("Sending file %s\n\n", source_file);
    FILE* f = fopen(source_file, "r");

    // send the contents of the file
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f)){
        printf("Sending %s", buffer);
        if(send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) == -1)
            perror("Error while sending\n");
        else printf("Successfully sent\n\n");
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }

    printf("File transfer complete\n");
    fclose(f);
}
```

### client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 8080

void main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    long val;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    char buffer[1024] = {0};

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr) == -1){
        perror("Invalid IP value");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address)) == -1){
        perror("Connection Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else printf("Connected to server\n");

    // Get file name from server
    if(read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == -1){
        perror("Could not read filename from server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Receiving file %s\n", buffer);
    FILE *f = fopen(buffer, "w");
    // printf("%ld", read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));

    while((val = read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))){
        if (val == 0) break;
        if (val == -1) {
            perror("Error reading the content");
            break;
        }
        printf("Read returned %ld\n", val);
        
        printf("Received %s", buffer);
        fputs(buffer, f);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }

    printf("File transfer complete\n");
    fclose(f);
}
```

Sample text file for data transfer

```
Hello there!
Nice to meet you.
This is a text file.
Bye Bye :)
Have a good day.
```

Execution from server side

```
$ cc ./server.c -o server
$ ./server
Connected to client
Sending file /home/username/Documents/something.txt

Sending Hello there!
Successfully sent

Sending Nice to meet you.
Successfully sent

Sending This is a text file.
Successfully sent

Sending Bye Bye :)
Successfully sent

Sending Have a good day.
Successfully sent

File transfer complete
```

This was the output I got from the server-side. This is weird because on client-side I didn't receive any message

```
$ cc ./client.c -o client
$ ./client
Connected to server
Receiving file something.txt
File transfer complete
```

The while loop in client side did not execute at all (because the data within buffer wasn't printed) and the read function did not return -1 otherwise a proper message would have been displayed.

This exact client code only works sometimes and other times it doesn't. What's the problem here?

Comment: `send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)` sends the string without the null terminator.

Comment: `read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer))` does not check how many bytes it received.  Note that recv data does not necessarily match boundaries of send.

Comment: this kind of statement should also be in the client: `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Read returned %ld\n", val);`  since this message was not output, this call: `while((val = read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))){` returned 0